# DotNet SMTPMailclient with username as first part of email address not working

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I am trying to establish a mail client connection with my mail server, where my mail server accepts just the first part of email rather the full one. 
Doing so in the program yields me an exception that the specified username string is not in a valid format.
Here is the code used

```
SMTPMailClient client = new SMTPMailClient("Vijay", "Password1", server, port, subject, body, 
this.ssl.Checked);
```

This statement works with a mail server accepting email address, wherein I supply the username as  "vijay@xxxxx.com"

Comment: thats a .net framework builtin

Answer (score 0):

The client you use can't be found when googling. But a mail needs a sender, a most likely the class you use wants an address as both username and sender address.

You could always use [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) to send the mail instead.